# Change body background image with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I decided to make a function that changes the body background image after every 10 seconds.

```
function Background()
{
    var Background_Stage;
    switch(Background_Stage)
    {
        case 0:
        {
            $('body').css.('background', '#000 url(../../Styles/Callum_Project1/Images/BACKGROUND_1_TEST.png) no-repeat');
            Background_Stage++;
            setInterval(function(){Background()},10000);
        }
        case 1:
        {
            $('body').css.('background', '#000 url(../../Styles/Callum_Project1/Images/BACKGROUND_2_TEST.png) no-repeat');
            Background_Stage++;
            setInterval(function(){Background()},10000);
        }
        case 2:
        {
            $('body').css.('background', '#000 url(../../Styles/Callum_Project1/Images/BACKGROUND_2_TEST.png) no-repeat');
            Background_Stage = 0;//Reset 
            setInterval(function(){Background()},10000);
        }
    }
}
```

However hen I did something like this

```
<body onload="Background()"></body>
```

It doesn't seem to do anything, this might be a dumb thing to ask for help with but this is the first I did when I was learning JavaScript, I should say that I used jQuery for most of this.

Comment: From Where are you getting `Background_Stage` variable value?

Comment: You have an extra . after .css

Comment: Please see my updated answer. Much simpler and no need for jQuery. I included notes so you can follow what is going on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a few problems with your code:

- The value of Background_Stage won't persist between calls to Background, and in any case, you never assign a value to Background_Stage.
- Use setTimeout rather than setInterval. setTimeout will call the function once at the end of the allotted time. setInterval will keep calling the same function again and again until explicitly cancelled. The way you have it, you'll end up with lots of concurrent setIntervals running.
- You don't need the '.' between css and the following parenthesis.

Finally, try not to repeat yourself, meaning that if you find yourself typing out more or less the same statements over and over, then you can probably make the code cleaner. Something like:

```
(function() 
{
    var bgCounter = 0,
        backgrounds = [
           "../../Styles/Callum_Project1/Images/BACKGROUND_1_TEST.png",
           "../../Styles/Callum_Project1/Images/BACKGROUND_2_TEST.png",
           "../../Styles/Callum_Project1/Images/BACKGROUND_3_TEST.png"
        ];
    function changeBackground()
    {
        bgCounter = (bgCounter+1) % backgrounds.length;
        $('body').css('background', '#000 url('+backgrounds[bgCounter]+') no-repeat');
        setTimeout(changeBackground, 10000);

    }
    changeBackground();
})();
```

Now changing the background URLs or adding more is a simple job of editing the backgrounds array.

Comment: This answer is pretty bad on account of you're encouraging this awful approach at all. This breaks the "dry" principle about as much as possible. It would be better to either simply address the issue and not propose that using all of that bad code is a good idea, or write a better solution out for him (good teaching opportunity).

Comment: Yeah there are much better ways to do it, but I figured it would be helpful to take what was written and fix it so the asker can easily see where he/she was going wrong.

Answer (score 2):

You can also try this:

```
function Background(){
    var imgs = [
            "../../Styles/Callum_Project1/Images/BACKGROUND_1_TEST.png",
            "../../Styles/Callum_Project1/Images/BACKGROUND_2_TEST.png",
            "../../Styles/Callum_Project1/Images/BACKGROUND_3_TEST.png"
        ],
        len = imgs.length,
        idx = -1;

    setInterval(function(){
        idx = (idx+1)%len;
        $("body").css("background", "#000 url("+imgs[idx]+")");
    }, 10000);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Every time you call background, you instantiate a new *local* variable called `Background_Stage` with a value of `undefined`. This doesn't match any of your `switch` options.

You need to declare the variable outside of your function (so it persists between calls to the function) and give it a starting value.

Comment: $('body').css.('background'... must be  $('body').css('background',... without the dot after css

Answer (score 0):

- Your `Backgroud_Stage` is not initialized
- Your `setInterval` placement will cause very serious problems
- There's also invalid syntax.

Overall, your code can be simpler like this:

```
var Stage = 0;
setInterval(function() {
    var bg = '#000 url(../../Styles/Callum_Project1/Images/BACKGROUND_'+(Stage+1)+'_TEST.png) no-repeat';
    document.body.style.background = bg;
    Stage = ++Stage % 3;
}, 10000);
```